# jQuery check if 4 fields are filled in

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am working on a form with 4 fields which I directly validate. So if a field is filled in correctly I give this field green borders for example. But now I want to do a check if all the fields are filled in and then I show a message.

My idea is to first make a function for each field like this below. And then check the 4 functions if they return true. But that didn't work, so I first check a single function (in this example for the field 'width') if they match, an alert returns. But this also doesn't work, so I cannot go any further now.

Can anybody help me to make this function work first?

(The `#config-steps #width` is an input field with the an id 'width')

My code snippet:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // Validate text fields
  $("#config-steps #width, #config-steps #height").on('input', function() {
    var input = $(this);
    var width = input.val();

    if (width.match(/^\d+$/)) {
      input.removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
      input.parents('li').find('.step-number').removeClass('unvalid-step').addClass('valid-step');
    } else {
      input.removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
      input.parents('li').find('.step-number').removeClass('valid-step').addClass('unvalid-step');
    }
  });

  // Validate select box
  $("#config-steps #type").change(function() {
    var slct = $(this);
    var type = slct.val()

    if (type) {
      slct.parents('li').find('.step-number').removeClass('unvalid-step').addClass('valid-step');
    } else {
      slct.parents('li').find('.step-number').removeClass('valid-step').addClass('unvalid-step');
    }

  });


  // Check all fields filled in.
  function check_field() {

    function validate_width() {
      var width = $("#config-steps #width").val();
      if (width.match(/^\d+$/)) {
        alert('test');
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }

  }

});
```

```css
.valid {
  background: #f7fff7 !important;
  border: 1px solid #459b40 !important;
}

.invalid {
  background: #fff7f7 !important;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000 !important;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

#config-steps li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #f6f8f9;
}

#config-steps li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e6ea;
  padding: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}

#config-steps li .step-number {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #f08f02;
  border: 1px solid #d98c1a;
  padding: 8px 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  float: left;
  min-width: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0 1px #FFF;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0 1px #FFF;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0 1px #FFF;
}

#config-steps li .valid-step {
  background: #55ad50;
  border: 1px solid #2b8825;
}

#config-steps li .unvalid-step {
  background: #ed7171;
  border: 1px solid #cf0000;
}

#config-steps li .step-description {
  font-size: 14px;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}

#config-steps li .step-action {
  float: right;
}

#config-steps li .step-action .textfield {
  background: #f1f9ff;
  border: 1px solid #9eabb6;
  padding: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#config-steps li .step-action input[type="text"] {
  width: 180px;
  text-align: right;
}

#config-steps li .step-action input[type="text"]:focus {
  background: #fffcf6;
  border: 1px solid #f6a41d;
}

#config-steps li .step-action select {
  margin: 7px 3px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="config">
  <ul id="config-steps">
    <li> <span class="step-number">1</span>

      <p class="step-description">Width (mm)</p>
      <div class="step-action">
        <input autofocus type="text" class="textfield" id="width" />
      </div>
      <!--End step-action-->
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
    <li> <span class="step-number">2</span>

      <p class="step-description">Height (mm)</p>
      <div class="step-action">
        <input type="text" class="textfield" id="height" />
      </div>
      <!--End step-action-->
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
    <li> <span class="step-number">3</span>

      <p class="step-description">Glasstype (mm)</p>
      <div class="step-action">
        <select id="type">
          <option value="">-- Select glasstype --</option>
          <option value="1">Mat</option>
          <option value="2">Glossy</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <!--End step-action-->
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!--End config-steps-->
</form>
<!--End config-->
```

Comment: Can you post here the HTML markup as well and possibly set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code demonstrating the issue, please?

Comment: You need to `return true` after the alert.

Comment: You should provide a jsfiddle with all relevant code. This kind of behaviour should be checked on FORM submit. And you could use some specific attribute as `required` and set element style using some CSS pseudo class as `:valid`, etc... Indeed, looks like you are overcomplicating it here

Comment: @JohnBupit Yeah I know, but to test this single version I only do a test alert.

Comment: @PetrR. Okay I'll gonna make a jsfiddle for you. One moment please

Comment: @Robbert: Need more code.

Comment: Okay, here is my jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EsBTg/ As you can see I first check the fields and then I want to check all 3 so I can show a message if they all 3 are filled in correctly. I don't want to use a submit at this moment. (I left one step because it was irrelevant)

Comment: Where do you call `check_field()`?

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to do since you don't call `check_field()` or `validate_width()` anywhere. [Maybe something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/6FR2W/)

Comment: But is there no possibility to check the 3 fields and then show a message if they are filled in correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$('#width').change` for checking

```
$('input,select').change(function(){
var width = $("#config-steps #width").val();
var height = $("#config-steps #height").val();
var size = $("#config-steps select").val();

    if (width.match(/^\d+$/)&&height.match(/^\d+$/)&&size.match(/^\d+$/)) {
        alert('Well done!');
    } else {
        return false;

  }
});
```

Updated here:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // Validate text fields
  $("#config-steps #width, #config-steps #height").on('input', function() {
    var input = $(this);
    var width = input.val();

    if (width.match(/^\d+$/)) {
      input.removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
      input.parents('li').find('.step-number').removeClass('unvalid-step').addClass('valid-step');
    } else {
      input.removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
      input.parents('li').find('.step-number').removeClass('valid-step').addClass('unvalid-step');
    }
  });

  // Validate select box
  $("#config-steps #type").change(function() {
    var slct = $(this);
    var type = slct.val()

    if (type) {
      slct.parents('li').find('.step-number').removeClass('unvalid-step').addClass('valid-step');
    } else {
      slct.parents('li').find('.step-number').removeClass('valid-step').addClass('unvalid-step');
    }

  });


  // Check all fields filled in.
  $('input,select').change(function() {
    var width = $("#config-steps #width").val();
    var height = $("#config-steps #height").val();
    var size = $("#config-steps select").val();

    if (width.match(/^\d+$/) && height.match(/^\d+$/) && size.match(/^\d+$/)) {
      alert('Well done!');
    } else {
      return false;

    }
  });


});
```

```css
.valid {
  background: #f7fff7 !important;
  border: 1px solid #459b40 !important;
}

.invalid {
  background: #fff7f7 !important;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000 !important;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

#config-steps li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #f6f8f9;
}

#config-steps li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e6ea;
  padding: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}

#config-steps li .step-number {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #f08f02;
  border: 1px solid #d98c1a;
  padding: 8px 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  float: left;
  min-width: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0 1px #FFF;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0 1px #FFF;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0 1px #FFF;
}

#config-steps li .valid-step {
  background: #55ad50;
  border: 1px solid #2b8825;
}

#config-steps li .unvalid-step {
  background: #ed7171;
  border: 1px solid #cf0000;
}

#config-steps li .step-description {
  font-size: 14px;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}

#config-steps li .step-action {
  float: right;
}

#config-steps li .step-action .textfield {
  background: #f1f9ff;
  border: 1px solid #9eabb6;
  padding: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#config-steps li .step-action input[type="text"] {
  width: 180px;
  text-align: right;
}

#config-steps li .step-action input[type="text"]:focus {
  background: #fffcf6;
  border: 1px solid #f6a41d;
}

#config-steps li .step-action select {
  margin: 7px 3px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="config">
  <ul id="config-steps">
    <li> <span class="step-number">1</span>

      <p class="step-description">Width (mm)</p>
      <div class="step-action">
        <input autofocus type="text" class="textfield" id="width" />
      </div>
      <!--End step-action-->
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
    <li> <span class="step-number">2</span>

      <p class="step-description">Height (mm)</p>
      <div class="step-action">
        <input type="text" class="textfield" id="height" />
      </div>
      <!--End step-action-->
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
    <li> <span class="step-number">3</span>

      <p class="step-description">Glasstype (mm)</p>
      <div class="step-action">
        <select id="type">
          <option value="">-- Select glasstype --</option>
          <option value="1">Mat</option>
          <option value="2">Glossy</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <!--End step-action-->
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!--End config-steps-->
</form>
<!--End config-->
```

Comment: But how can I check the 3 fields now? I need to check If field 1, 2 and 3 are filled in correctly and then show a message for example with 'Well done!'

Comment: @Robbert,Check my updated answer and fiddle.I think that was you needed

Comment: Why would you add additional listeners? Just run a function. http://jsfiddle.net/EsBTg/10/

Comment: @marcjae I think this is almost what I need. I only have one last question: Can I use the change function also for a custom made color selector. That is the fourth step, but is no normal html input type.

Comment: Maybe add a hidden input, which you populate once a color has been selected. Then you can use the same function to validate

Comment: You can try as @marcjae sujested

Comment: @marcjae I tried the hidden field, but for some reason he doesn't see the adding to the color hidden field as a change. Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Robbert, you don't have to listen to the event, since you know when it has been added (as you populate the data yourself). So all you have to do is, after you update the hidden field call validate(). You just need to ensure the color input value regex check is present in the validate function.

Comment: @marcjae Thanks for your answer! I do not think I completely understand, but is validate() not a extension of jQuery? (Sorry, I'm a beginner). I now did it by placing .change() after updating the hidden field value and that worked.

Comment: Ok @Robbert let me try explain it a little better. If you look at the following fiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/EsBTg/10/, after every "change" event, we call the function validate(). So after you update the hidden input, just call that function and it should validate all the required inputs. You do get a plugin called "validate" for jQuery, but that separate and isn't required. All we doing is calling the function we created. It just so happens to be named similar to an extension that already exists.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call the

```
check_field();
```

Function after each input has been updated. I've created an example of how you can achieve this.

http://jsfiddle.net/EsBTg/6/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [***`.each()`*** function](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) in jQuery to test several elements at once:

```
function validate_width() {
    var error = 0;
    $("#width, #height, #type").each(function () {
        if (!$(this).val().match(/^\d+$/)) {
            error++;
        }
    });
    if (!error){
        alert("Everything's fine!");
    }    
}
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // Validate text fields
  $("#config-steps #width, #config-steps #height").on('input', function() {
    var input = $(this);
    var width = input.val();

    if (width.match(/^\d+$/)) {
      input.removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
      input.parents('li').find('.step-number').removeClass('unvalid-step').addClass('valid-step');
    } else {
      input.removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
      input.parents('li').find('.step-number').removeClass('valid-step').addClass('unvalid-step');
    }
  });

  // Validate select box
  $("#config-steps #type").change(function() {
    var slct = $(this);
    var type = slct.val()

    if (type) {
      slct.parents('li').find('.step-number').removeClass('unvalid-step').addClass('valid-step');
    } else {
      slct.parents('li').find('.step-number').removeClass('valid-step').addClass('unvalid-step');
    }

  });


  // Check all fields filled in.


  function validate_width() {
    var error = 0;
    $("#width, #height, #type").each(function() {
      if (!$(this).val().match(/^\d+$/)) {
        error++;
      }
    });
    if (error) {
      alert("There were " + error + " errors.");
    } else {
      alert("Everything's fine!");
    }
  }
  $("#check").click(function() {
    validate_width();
  })


});
```

```css
.valid {
  background: #f7fff7 !important;
  border: 1px solid #459b40 !important;
}

.invalid {
  background: #fff7f7 !important;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000 !important;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

#config-steps li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #f6f8f9;
}

#config-steps li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e6ea;
  padding: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}

#config-steps li .step-number {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #f08f02;
  border: 1px solid #d98c1a;
  padding: 8px 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  float: left;
  min-width: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0 1px #FFF;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0 1px #FFF;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0 1px #FFF;
}

#config-steps li .valid-step {
  background: #55ad50;
  border: 1px solid #2b8825;
}

#config-steps li .unvalid-step {
  background: #ed7171;
  border: 1px solid #cf0000;
}

#config-steps li .step-description {
  font-size: 14px;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}

#config-steps li .step-action {
  float: right;
}

#config-steps li .step-action .textfield {
  background: #f1f9ff;
  border: 1px solid #9eabb6;
  padding: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#config-steps li .step-action input[type="text"] {
  width: 180px;
  text-align: right;
}

#config-steps li .step-action input[type="text"]:focus {
  background: #fffcf6;
  border: 1px solid #f6a41d;
}

#config-steps li .step-action select {
  margin: 7px 3px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="config">
  <ul id="config-steps">
    <li> <span class="step-number">1</span>

      <p class="step-description">Width (mm)</p>
      <div class="step-action">
        <input autofocus type="text" class="textfield" id="width" />
      </div>
      <!--End step-action-->
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
    <li> <span class="step-number">2</span>

      <p class="step-description">Height (mm)</p>
      <div class="step-action">
        <input type="text" class="textfield" id="height" />
      </div>
      <!--End step-action-->
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
    <li> <span class="step-number">3</span>

      <p class="step-description">Glasstype (mm)</p>
      <div class="step-action">
        <select id="type">
          <option value="">-- Select glasstype --</option>
          <option value="1">Mat</option>
          <option value="2">Glossy</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <!--End step-action-->
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!--End config-steps-->
</form>
<!--End config-->
<input id=check value=Check type=button>
```